After manually setting datasource it broke all @Scheduled spring boot
The datasource was set on application.properties and many services would make cronjobs, through @Scheduled, using the repositories, JpaRepositories, from the main datasource, after some time in order to use multiple databases I configured the main datasource manually as follows:
@DependsOn("assinanteContext")
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"org.crm"
        }, // Adjusted package for primary repositories
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mainEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mainTransactionManager",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
                AssinanteRepository.class
        }
        )
)
public class DataSourceConfig{

    @Autowired
    private AssinanteContext assinanteContext;

    @Value("${app.assinante-cnpj}")
    private String cnpj;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(assinanteContext.dbURL);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(assinanteContext.dbUser);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(assinanteContext.dbPass);

        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(3000);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(60000);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(1800000);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(5);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(20);

        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mainEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("org.crm"); // Main packages to scan
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager mainTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory mainEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mainEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}

It's not annoted as @Primary because it depends from assinanteContext service, that's another service which contains some dynamic env values to make the connection to the main database (those values are requested from another database), the datasource containing this env values was configured as follows:
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.crm.domain.entidadesBusiness.assinantesSistema", // Pacote onde está o repositório do Assinante
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "assinanteEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "assinanteTransactionManager"
)
public class AssinanteDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource assinanteDataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("scrt");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("scrt");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("v");

        // Configurações do HikariCP
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(3000);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(60000);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(1800000);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(5);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(20);

        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean assinanteEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(assinanteDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(Assinante.class.getPackageName());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager assinanteTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory assinanteEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(assinanteEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}

The problem is after I set those configs all cron job methods consuming the repositories from main Datasource got broken when persisting an entity, for example
@Scheduled
@Transactional
public void someCrudUsingSpringDataJpaRepository(){//logic}

was used to persist entities by doing some repository.save() statements.... after those configurations it still executes repository.save() with no error but no entity is persisted to database unless I call this cronjob method through a http request by @RestController.
I don't have any ideia what's happening and I think it's a SpringBoot bug
